# Automatic alignment of controls in Access 2007

Tags: alignment, ms-access-2007

I created a form in Access 2007 that shows contact data and data from a person. This data is separated in the backend and shall also in the frontend. So I created a tab control with two tabs. If a user clicked on Contact, then the data Telephone, Fax and Email should be shown. If the user clicked on Data, Title, Firstname and Lastname should be shown and be aligned to the left.

[image: tab control with data]

The problem now is that when I set the visibility of telephone, fax and email on false and the width on '0' in vba, then the elements title, firstname and lastname remain on the right side. How can I set the alignment of the elements in the form, so that they are aligned to the left side (where before the elements telephone, fax and email have been)?

Also I want them not to be in the same place when I drag them in design mode. In other forms, the behavior is like that, that means when I drag an element onto another, they are arranged side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy: You can set the layout of the textboxes to 'table'. Then an extra header is generated which you can layout as the headers on the picture for example. Because the textboxes are now tables, they automatically align to the direction you put in the properties 'horizontal achor' and 'vertical anchor'.